# Imported TLS-certificate does not show up in App Service

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I have a strange problem when importing a certificate from Azure Key vault to be used in an App Service. As you can see in the images below, it says the certificate is imported successfully but it does not show up as expected.

This have previous worked just fine for other app services and my custom domain matches the wildcard certificate that I am trying to use.

Any ideas what causes this strange behavior?

[image: tls1]

[image: tls2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I made a workaround solution by setting an Managed Identity on my App Service giving it correct permissions to the keyvault. And then adding the application and correct permissions in Access policies for the keyvault.

After that the certificate showed up as expected when adding a binding on my App Service.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to upload or import a private certificate to App Service, your certificate must meet the following requirements:

- Exported as a password-protected PFX file, encrypted using triple DES.
- Contains private key at least 2048 bits long
- Contains all intermediate certificates in the certificate chain

Some certificate authorities provide certificates in different formats, therefore before importing the certificate, make sure that they are either in .pem or .pfx format.

> When you are importing the certificate, you need to ensure that the
> key is included in the file itself. If you have the private key
> separately in a different format, you would need to combine the key
> with the certificate.

you can also refer  https://www.huuhka.net/app-service-imported-ssl-certificate-from-another-subscription-kv/   if you have any failure messages while importing the key vault certificate

If you are using free managed certificate , you may check its pre-requisites to be fulfilled as free certificates come with few limitations , which can be referred  from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003781#private-certificate-requirements

Answer (score 0):

Seems you got the right solutions and might have encountered this issue due to your logged in user RBAC role.
When ever you use app service certificate it gets stored inside Azure Key vault and to use that key vault certificate/secret you need to have access policies to get the secret and set the secret.
More details at:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy-portal#:~:text=Assign%20an%20access%20policy%201%20In%20the%20Azure,the%20Principal%20selection%20pane.%20...%20More%20items...%20](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy-portal#:%7E:text=Assign%20an%20access%20policy%201%20In%20the%20Azure,the%20Principal%20selection%20pane.%20...%20More%20items...%20)